# TabHost keeps adding the dynamic tabs when app restarts after Back Button pressed

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabwidget, android-framelayout

I'm creating the 3 tabs dynamically based on example here http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

the application works well except one issue.
when I launch app and then click the Back Button then the app closes.
I launched the app by clicking on the application icon.
now I can see 6 tabs. each time I repeat this process, it keeps on adding 3 tabs.
when ever I use Menu button instead of back Button then it doesn't add 3 tabs.

anything going wrong here, how can I fix it?

thanks

Comment: Can you post some code ? your life cycle methods to be exact...

Comment: oops my bad...I shouldn't add tabs on every create method....now I'm keeping static array list of tabs labels. so in onCreate(...) method, I'm adding to the list only if it is empty. this fixed the issue...so on Back-Button->relaunch onCreate is called how come its not called for HomeButton->relaunch..I'm still confused.

Comment: This is because the back button kills your activity, the home button kind of puts it on hold.

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating the tabs at `onResume()` or `onStart()`? Try to create them at `onCreate()`
or delete the tabs by `onPause` with something like:

```
LinearLayout tabbar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabbar);
tabbar.removeAllViews();
```